# Как сократить количество блоков try-catch при закрытии подключения к БД?

Tags: java, try-catch

Есть код, который выполняет запрос к БД:

```
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM motor AS m WHERE m.id_motor > (?)");
    statement.setInt(1, 0);
    rs = statement.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String res = String.format("%s %s", rs.getInt("id_motor"), rs.getString("name"));
        System.out.println(res);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        assert rs != null;
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Я хочу сократить количество блоков `try-catch` в `finally` - уж очень грязно получается. Как это можно сделать более цивилизованно? Может, как-то задействовав *try-with-resources* или что-то еще? Но только так, чтобы функциональность не повредить (в плане закрытия ресурсов).

Comment: Конструкция _try-with-resources_ как раз для избавления от такого блока `finally` и была придумана. Так что её и используйте.

Comment: Можно использовать try-with-resources, но её можно использовать не всегда. Можешь ещё пробовать закрывать ресурсы так   private void closeSQL(AutoCloseable... autoCloseable) {
        for (AutoCloseable closeable : autoCloseable) {
            try {
                closeable.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @Regent да но они не лезут в try-with-resources я хотел сразу это сделать но компилятор подчеркивает что нельзя...

Comment: Кстати, да. В данном примере вполне хватит _try-with-resources_, но в общем случае можно создать метод в helper-классе в виде `public static void closeResource(AutoCloseable resource) { ... }`. Либо сразу на несколько ресурсов, как показано выше - тогда не придётся на каждый ресурс вызывать метод..

Comment: @Regent я понял почему то try-with-resources заставляет меня объявлять переменную в своей сигнатуре... Да я и не настаиваю большое спасибо что ответили я уж думал оно в трай вообще не лезет а теперь оказывается лезет...

Comment: @Павел ну, думаю, за установку JDK и NetBeans меня не уволят. Примеры обоих вариантов привёл в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С использованием конструкции *try-with-resources* получается так:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM motor AS m WHERE m.id_motor > (?)";
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query))
{
    statement.setInt(1, 0);
    try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery())
    {
        while (rs.next())
        {
            String res = String.format("%s %s", rs.getInt("id_motor"), rs.getString("name"));
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Если закрывать ресурс нужно в другом методе (например, если соединение к БД `connection` устанавливается на время обработки всех SQL-запросов), то можно написать вспомогательный метод для закрытия ресурса:

```
public static void closeResource(AutoCloseable resource)
{
    if (resource != null)
    {
        try
        {
            resource.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ignored) { }
    }
}
```

И использовать его по необходимости. В данном случае блок `finally` будет выглядеть так:

```
finally
{
    closeResource(rs);
    closeResource(statement);
    closeResource(connection);
}
```

---

Метод `closeResource` можно расширить для обработки нескольких ресурсов сразу (как предложил @МихаилКетов):

```
public static void closeResources(AutoCloseable... resources)
{
    for (AutoCloseable resource : resources)
    {
        if (resource != null)
        {
            try
            {
                resource.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ignored) { }
        }
    }
}
```

И, соответственно, использование:

```
finally
{
    closeResources(rs, statement, connection);
}
```